# visit function opens invalid URL

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am new to `cypress` and writing my 1st test.

In my test, I have the following script:

```
describe('Navigate to login page', function() {
  it('successfully loads', function() {
    cy.visit('https://www.google.com')
  })
})
```

When running with `TestRunner`, it opens the page with the following URL:

```
https://www.google.com/__/#/tests/integration\login_spec.js
```

Is there any way to remove the appended text `__/#/tests/integration\login_spec.js` in the `url`?

Thanks,
Tuyen

Comment: Cypress appends that to the end to load its tools.  I don't think there's a way to remove it.  The page displayed is actually `https://www.google.com/`

Comment: Hi Brendan, because Cypress adds text like "_/tests/..." so I couldn't load the page. The browser tried to open https://www.google.com/__/#/tests/integration\login_spec.js instead of https://www.google.com.

Comment: If you copy the link from the test runner broswer and paste it elsewhere it will not work, but that is standard and expected for the test runner - that's the thing that opens up when you run `cypress open`.  Click on your test, and it opens a browser window with that URL.

Comment: that `__/#/tests/integration\login_spec.js` url you see atop the testRunner window has nothing to do with actual app's (AUT) url you visit, otherwise the tests would never work, obviously (irrespective if you're visiting local, or remote address). What exact problem are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`cy.url()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/url.html#Syntax) to get the current url of the app you're testing.

for example

```
cy.url().then(url => console.log(url))
```

The app url is shown above your test page. See here

[image]